# Use word2vec to expand a glossary in order to classify texts

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I have a database containing about 3 million texts (tweets). I put clean texts (removing stop words, tags...) in a list of lists of tokens called `sentences` (so it contains a list of tokens for each text).

After these steps, if I write

`model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)`

I obtain a vocabulary of about 400,000 words.

I have also a list of words (belonging to the same topic, in this case: economics) called `terms`. I found that 7% of the texts contain at least one of these words (so we can say that 7% of total tweets talk about economics).

My goal is to expand the list `terms` in order to retrieve more texts belonging to the economic topic.

Then I use

`results = model.most_similar(terms, topn=5000)`

to find, within the list of lists of tokens `sentences`, the words most similar to those contained in `terms`.

Finally if I create the data frame

`df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['key', 'similarity'])`

I get something like that:

```
key       similarity
word1     0.795432
word2     0.787954
word3     0.778942
...       ...
```

Now I think I have two possibilities to define the expanded glossary:

- I take the first N words (what should be the value of N?);
- I look at the suggested words one by one and decide which one to include in the expanded glossary based on my knowledge (does this word really belong to the economic glossary?)

How should I proceed in a case like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no general answer for what the cutoff should be, or how much you should use your own manual judgement versus cruder (but fast/automatic) processes. Those are inherently decisions which will be heavily influenced by your data, model quality, & goals – so you have to try different approaches & see what works there.

If you had a goal for what percentage of the original corpus you want to take – say, 14% instead of 7% – you could go as deeply into the ranked candidate list of 'similar words' as necessary to hit that 14% target.

Note that when you retrieve `model.most_similar(terms)`, you are asking the model to 1st average all words in `terms` together, then return words close to that one average point. To the extent your seed set of terms is tightly around the idea of `economics`, that might find words close to that generic average idea – but might not find other interesting words, such as close sysnonyms of your seed words that you just hadn't thought of. For that, you might want to get not 5000 neighbors for one generic average point, but (say) 3 neighbors for every individual term. To the extent the 'shape' of the topic isn't a perfect sphere around someplace in the word-vector-space, but rather some lumpy complex volume, that might better reflect your intent.

Instead of using your judgement of the candidate words standing alone to decide whether a word is `economics`-related, you could instead look at the texts that a word uniquely brings in. That is, for new word X, look at the N texts that contain that word. How many, when applying your full judgement to their full text, deserve to be in your 'economics' subset? Only if it's above some threshold T would you want to move X into your glossary.

But such an exercise may just highlight: using a simple glossary – "for any of these hand-picked N words, every text mentioning at least 1 word is in" – is a fairly crude way of assessing a text's topic. There are other ways to approach the goal of "pick a relevant subset" in an automated way.

For example, you could view your task as that of training a text binary classifier to classify texts as 'economics' or 'not-economics'.

In such a case, you'd start with some training data - a set of example documents that are already labeled 'economics' or 'not-economics', perhaps via individual manual review, or perhaps via some crude bootstrapping (like labeling all texts with some set of glossary words as 'economics', & all others 'not-economics'). Then you'd draw from the full range of potential text-preprocessing, text-feature-extracton, & classification options to train & evaluate classifiers that make that judgement for you. Then you'd evaluate/tune those – a process wich might also improve your training data, as you add new definitively 'economics' or 'not-economics' texts – & eventually settle on one that works well.

Alternatively, you could use some other richer topic-modeling methods (LDA, word2vec-derived `Doc2Vec`, deeper neural models etc) for modeling the whole dataset, then from some seed-set of definite-'economics' texts, expand outward from them – finding nearest-examples to known-good documents, either auto-including them or hand-reviewing them.

Separately: `min_count=1` is almost always a mistake in word2vec & related algorihtms, which do better if you *discard* words so rare they lack the variety of multiple usage examples the algorithm needs to generate good word-vectors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and especially for your advice on `min_count` and `most_similar`: I'll try it with one term at a time.

In your opinion, classifying a text based on the presence of a term belonging to a specific topic is a crude method even if the text is a tweet (therefore a very short text)? I mean, if I have a 10-word text and one of them is economic, the whole tweet is very likely to be about economics, right?

An additional curiosity: in general, is `word2vec` used to extend a glossary in order to collect more texts? That is, is it an established practice?

Comment: Compared to what smarter classifiers can do, yes, anything based on mere presence of individual words is fairly crude. If 100% of all tweets with the word `'economics'` are relevant, and you provide sufficient labeled training data to demonstrate that, then a good classifier, even on a simple 'bag of words' representation, will learn that - plus lots of other useful heuristics beyond what you would think to specify. For example, many classifiers would be able to deduce if 2 words together are a good signal for inclusion - even if either alone isn't.

Comment: Yes, word2vec can be used to expand word-lists with more similar words. But as above, using siple presence-or-absence of individual words will be very quickly outperformed by off-the-shelf classification techniques, so the exact sequence of steps you're pursuing isn't that common, in what I've seen.

Comment: Note though that word2vec similarity isn't strictly the same as synonymity - words that we'd consider opposites, like `'hot'` and `'cold'`, will be relatively close in most word2vec-style spaces, as they both are used in similar contexts, to describe a similar aspect of things. (Usually this is beneficial in the sort of broad-topical work you're doing, though it can present a challenge for other kinds of text-understanding.)

Comment: So word2vec can be used on tweets to expand economics terminology, but the criterion I use to determine whether a tweet is about economics or not is crude. So doesn't it make sense to use word2vec? Or rather, at this point expanding the economic glossary is an operation for its own sake?

Comment: It depends on other aspects of your goals not yet mentioned. Why do ou need a subset of 'economics' tweets? Why wasn't the initial quick-and-dirty 7% of 'economics' tweets enough? (Are you sure you even need to select out some subset, instead of using *all* the tweets, for whatever is the real goal?)

Comment: The future goal would be to conduct a sentiment analysis on tweets that contain the word coronavirus to describe the impact of the pandemic on the economy. For example the tweet "Coronavirus is destroying the economy." will be seen as an economic themed tweet with negative sentiment. On the other hand, the tweet "Production grows 2% after the first phase of the coronavirus." will be seen as an economic themed tweet with positive sentiment.

Comment: Aha. Well, choosing a few obvious anchor words is a quick-&-dirty reasonable start, & might even be sufficient. But if for some reason you think that's not giving enough data, or sufficient results – and it's not clear why your initial "7%" wasn't enough, sending you down this path – my point is that you don't need to be limited to the simple, "add N new words, take all tweets with any of those words" heuristic. You can use an initial set of in/out examples to train classifiers that use more-sophisticated multiword rules (& other text features).

Comment: Just for completeness, maybe they use a similar approach to mine: https://academic.oup.com/jamiaopen/article/2/2/246/5423083?login=true.